# sorted map in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, sortedmap

When creating a map from collections via apoc's `apoc.map.fromLists` (or plain cypher for all I care), is there any way to respect/keep the sorting? Or is it just "It's a map, sorting doesn't make sense anyway".

specifically, when executing

```
with [{name: "z", a: 1}, {name: "b", b: 1}, {name: "b2", b: 2}] as qs
return apoc.map.fromLists([q in qs | q.name], qs)
```

I get

```
{
  "b2": {
    "name": "b2",
    "b": 2
  },
  "z": {
    "name": "z",
    "a": 1
  },
  "b": {
    "name": "b",
    "b": 1
  }
}
```

where indeed I would like to have

```
{
  "z": {
    "name": "z",
    "a": 1
  },
  "b": {
    "name": "b",
    "b": 1
  },
  "b2": {
    "name": "b2",
    "b": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, maps in Cypher are unsorted and unsortable structures, with regard to map keys.

There is [apoc.maps.sortedProperties()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_map_functions), however this doesn't return a map, but a list of key/value pairs, where those pairs are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: I see, so there is no way to control the sorting of maps other than alphabetical keys?

Comment: Right, there is no concept in the map structures for ordering of keys. You would need to transform it to a non-map structure which could be sorted, such as the APOC function provided.